# Why is there vinegar in the bread recipe?

Tags: baking, vinegar, bread

Yesterday I made bread based on a recipe I found on the flour bag. It contained both rye and wheat flour but also three tablespoons of vinegar. I've never seen it used in bread before, why is it there?

Answer (score 14):

If it contained a high amount of rye flour, an acid would be needed for the bread to leaven. This is because bread with lots of rye rises due to polysaccharates called "pentosans" (if i remember correctly) being sticky and holding in the carbon dioxide bubbles. With heat, an enzyme in rye called "amylase" will start eating up the pentosans, unless the amylase is deactivated with acidity (wheat flour uses a protein called "gluten" to trap bubbles, and its amylase is deactivated with heat anyhow). The acidity is traditionally lactic acid, produced by lactobacilli bacteria in sourdough, but could be vinegar.

If it's mostly wheat flour (i.e. if you have to knead it), the vinegar would just be for flavour.

Answer (score 9):

Another reason you can use vinegar in a bread recipe - to produce a sourdough.  Under traditional methods of making a sourdough bread, one keeps a 'sour' (sponge) or a piece of dough from the days previous production, which acts as a starter for the current bread.  In many of todays commercial bakeries (grocery stores, etc.), sours are not kept from day to day, and powdered substitutes are used.  They are normally just a glorified acetic acid (in a powdered form).  So, you can just use vinegar to produce the same results.

Comment: Since there is rye in the dough, I could definitely see the intent being to produce a sourdough-like flavor.

Comment: Yep, that's right.  One thing that most people don't understand is that rye bread is a sourdough bread.  It's always made off of a rye sour.

Comment: This recipe didn't contain any sourdough starter of any kind, just yeast.

Comment: Oh, I never said it did have a sour starter.  The vinegar is used as a replacement for the starter.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the recipe. You can't leaven rye with yeast, the enzymes in the rye prevent it. Maybe, if it is a mixed recipe with a high wheat-to-rye ratio, the yeast will still work, but I'm not sure why you would need to imitate a sour taste through vinegar then.

Comment: You can't leaven rye with yeast because rye flour contains no gluten. Wheat is the only cereal crop with (high enough) gluten content to facilitate yeast leavening. As I said last year, all rye breads are sourdough breads, the vinegar is used as a shortcut for the 'sour' flavour.

Comment: You definitely can leaven rye with yeast. The enzymes in rye cause it's starches to convert to sugar quickly, so it's actually great for yeast. The issue is that since rye relies on gums for structure, it's difficult to retain the bubbles, no matter what's producing them.

Answer (score 5):

When I asked this question - [Is there anything I can add to homemade bread to preserve it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/is-there-anything-i-can-add-to-homemade-bread-to-preserve-it) - Arafangion said that one commercial bread company now uses vinegar as a preservative. This is his answer to my question:

> "One commercial bread company has
>   switched preservatives... They use
>   vinegar (I suspect ordinary white
>   vinegar).
>
> Maybe you could give a little bit of
>   vinegar a go and see how that works?
>   You can still smell it if you sniff
>   and sandwiches do have a faint vinegar
>   flavour, but it seems to work well
>   enough for the company and it
>   apparently hasn't sabotaged the
>   product line...
>
> Then again, it /is/ commercial
>   bread..."

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'd still like to think that there's another explanation. I've never seen homemade bread recipes that contains something which only purpose is acting as a preservative.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a lower pH (more acidity) weakens the gluten and makes the crumb less chewey or less rubbery.
Certainly one thing to try before taking the step of adding vinegar to a bread recipe is to replace any bread flour with general purpose flour instead -- it should have the same effect.

Comment: Never make a bread with an all-purpose flour.  Big no-no.  Acidity does not weaken the gluten, it serves to speed gluten formation.  This means that a bread will be properly mixed (gluten properly formed) sooner when you are mixing a sour bread when compared to mixing a 'regular' bread.   In turn, the dough will be over mixed if you mix it the same amount of time you would  mix that regular bread.  So the acidity just speeds up the whole gluten cycle.

Comment: @mrwienerdog: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19577/vinegar-in-pie-crust/19579#19579 with respect to acidity. Also I think you're being way too negative about all-purpose flour. It may not be ideal for breads, but it does work. And if you're trying to weaken gluten structure, well, bread flour's primary difference compared to all-purpose flour is increased gluten...

Comment: @mrwienerdog Acidity is used in bread dough as an oxidizer. It doesn't speed gluten formation, but it makes the links in the gluten stronger (frequently making the dough stiffer). Reducing agents are actually what speeds gluten formation, though they are frequently used in conjunction with an oxidizer.

Comment: You can't tell me that it doesn't speed gluten formation. That's simply not true. If you replace 5 percent of the water in your mix with vinegar, it will DEFINITELY be mixed quicker.

Answer (score 2):

In making faster no-Knead bread Jim Lahey suggest adding 4 drops or up to 1/4 tsp of red wine vinegar to the basic recipe. Improve gluten development and flavor. See the video with Mark Bittman here:
http://www.nytimes.com/2008/10/08/dining/08mini.html?ref=dining

Answer (score 0):

It might also, in addition to something like bicarbonate soda act as a raising agent for some types of bread - the reaction of the vinegar with the bicarb causing gas release causing rising.

This is only a guess however