# Why do some pie crust recipes include vinegar?

Tags: baking, dough, pie, vinegar, crust

I experiment some with pie crusts and have seen recipes that include vinegar as well as eggs. What does the vinegar do and what does the egg do.  I have heard the vinegar promotes tenderness but have read on one of the posts here that it speeds gluten formation.

Comment: Is the post you mention here [the comment on this answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/10642/1672)? I think it's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

From *On Food and Cooking*:

> Acidity in the dough - as from a sourdough culture - weakens the gluten network by increasing the number of positively charged amino acids along the protein chains, and increasing the repulsive force between chains.

And weaker gluten structure is definitely a good thing for pastry doughs!

From the same source:

> [Eggs] supplement gluten structure with tender protein coagulum, tenderize products; slow staling

So eggs help provide a more tender structure, again good for pastry doughs.

Comment: I've got some recipes for Flaky and Puff pastry that call for lemon juice, however the same book omits them from the shortcrust pastries.