# Make artisan bread last longer than 3-4 days (besides freezing)

Tags: bread

I make simple artisan bread (1 cup water, 2 cups flour, 1.5 tsp yeast, 1.5 tsp salt). It usually starts to look like mold spot start growing in about 4 - 5 days. Is there anything that could be added to the ingredients to make it last longer? Or any modifications to the recipe?

If possible, I'd prefer to add ingredients instead of extra steps like putting some in the freezer, or keep in air-tight container, etc.

Comment: I want to there was a question close to yours asked years ago … but all I’m finding is this somewhat related one: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/79026/67

Comment: I believe I was thinking about this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7804/67

Comment: @Joe. I would call that a duplicate.  I am deleting my answer and voting to close.

Comment: Yeah, feels like a duplicate.

Comment: I can't think in cups, because we bake by weight here, but I know my sourdough keeps less well in summer (warm humid kitchen) and less well since I reduced the salt in it. But I don't know how much salt you're using compared to me, and anyway the acidity and hydration both make a difference too

Comment: 1/2 cup water, 1 cup flour, 0.75 tsp yeast & salt, bake twice as often...or Eat More Bread.