# Home-made Burger buns food safety

Tags: food-safety, bread

How can I make burger buns that I can  keep for a long time?

I have tried making some, but fungus starts growing on them after just two days...

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add, how you prepared and stored your burger buns? And how long do you plan to keep them?

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars Thanks!  Missed that one!  **:-)**

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but the closest interpretation sounds like a duplicate of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/is-there-anything-i-can-add-to-homemade-bread-to-preserve-it.

Answer (score 5):

Best way to keep bread for a long time, more than 1 day, especially burger buns, which are more fragile than regular bread is to freeze them.

Slice them open and freeze them as quickly as possible, but in a freeze bag.

(edit)
If your buns start having fungus after just a couple of days, maybe there is something wrong with your recipe; could you share the recipe?

Answer (score 2):

I've also been making burger buns for more than a year now, including with egg wash and sesame on top (tip).

Best solution is to freeze them to keep them for more than a couple days.

You **can** also keep them a couple days, up to a week, without freezing using the following methods:

- Add a preservative. This may sound 'unnatural' but a very common preservative is E300, which is Vitamine C. Lemon juice!
- Store it in a paper bag, which will allow water vapor to escape and not create a too humid environment around the bread. Humid environments will cause fungus.

Good luck