# Bread going stale in enamel breadbasket

Tags: bread, storage-method

I store my bread in an enamel breadbasket like [this one](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/KCgAAOxydgZTJhrU/$_72.JPG) (different decor, though). In the bottom of the basket, there are some small holes, I think to let the air circulate. But bread stored in this basket goes stale in a matter of two or three days.

Any hints as to why and how to prevent it?

**EDIT:**

As I was made aware only later, my bread isn't going stale, rather it takes on too much moisture. Cross-language problems...

Comment: What type of bread? Preservative-laden or not?

Comment: Sadly it is non-self-made bread, but I have no idea about the bakery's recipes.

Comment: Your bread is still going stale, separately from gathering moisture. See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-storing-bread-in-various-locations?rq=1 and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/whats-the-purpose-of-a-bread-box?lq=1. Basically, whatever is happening, you cannot expect to store white bread for three days and keep it at good quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinary everyday bread made from flour, salt, yeast and water from a bakery should be stale by the third day. That is what happens to it naturally, unless it is packed with preservatives and kept in a polythene bag. A larger loaf will possibly stay fresher longer, but looks like your container only holds fairly small loaves and rolls (which will dry out and go stale quickest).

A "natural" or artisan-made loaf will no longer be "fresh" from the day after purchase. By day two it is best for making toast, then from day three: toast, bread crumbs, stuffing, dumplings, rissoles, bread puddings and all the other luscious food and creative uses our grandmothers had for using up the stale bread in their pantries.

A good or rather a well designed bread bin (or bread box in the USA) will be well ventilated and will allow bread to dry out without becoming mouldy. Sounds like yours is just right.

Comment: It seems I got the meaning of "stale" all wrong then: The bread takes on moisture and if I don't have a look every other day, it can go moldy.

Comment: Ah, yes, "stale" is when bread dries out. I had wondered at such a closed bread bin working. Well you will probably be able to solve your mouldy bread problem by acquiring a more appropriate holder. I have a large crock pot with a tea towel over it. There is enough ventilation and air around the bread to prevent mould forming, or rather enough to make sure the bread dries out and so is not moist enough for mould to start growing.

Comment: So there's no easy way to continue with the enamel basket?

Comment: This is only my opinion, @Thaoden but unless you can get more air circulation, it is not going to help. There are silicates and other moisture absorbers you could try out, but I have no experience of them and am not sure about toxicity issues.

Comment: @Thaoden There can be other factors at work here which you have not mentioned. Are you putting defrosted bread in there? Or hot new-baked bread? Is it in a warm place near a heat source or in a sunny window? Are there changes in temperature over 24 hrs? All sorts of reasons, and depending on which one or combination, whether the bin is right for you or not. If there are holes in the base, then you could look at putting it onto a coaster. Clean it out with boiling water and bicarbonate of soda, then try wrapping your bread in a cloth instead of "bare" or in plastic.

Comment: I don't use the bread basekt anymore, but wrap it in some linen cloth now. Works better it seems. Thanks for your help here!

Comment: I am glad you have found a solution.