# Why my dinner rolls get dry after two days?

Tags: bread, storage-lifetime

I bake eggless dinner rolls at home, also known as “Paav”in many countries.
I use  dry yeast to make dough. Also, use sugar for  yeast fermentation, and butter and salt as per the requirements. I bake it @ 360 F for 25-30 minutes. It comes out really soft and in a good texture. Everyone enjoys it’s taste at home.
However, the texture of the rolls stays same for at most two days max then it gets dry and hard. I don’t realize what wrong am I doing. I also, wrap left over rolls air tight with sealing wrap.

I would appreciate your answer.

Comment: All bread will go stale within a few days after baking. See for example [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/49629/22591).

Comment: Agree with LSchoon - you are not doing anything wrong, that's very normal for bread. I chose several questions on bread storage as duplicate targets, you can read through them to see if you can get any better by following them.

Comment: 'Dry' & 'stale' are not really the same thing. For 'dry' you can pat with wet hands & fresh up in the oven.

Comment: This is partly an advert for a bread product, but does explain the difference & also reiterates my method for rehydrating dry bread - http://bridgebread.org/FreshDryStale

Comment: @Tetsujin Actually, "freshening up" bread in the oven works to undo staling (i.e., mostly reverses the starch retrogradation that causes staleness). The patting with water prevents the bread from drying out too much while doing this. I wonder if we have a question on the subject...