# How do you prolong buns/rolls/scone/crumpet softness?

Tags: bread, storage-method, fresh

I thought this community is appropriate for this question so I want to know how to keep buns/rolls/scone/crumpet softness longer. In English I see several translations for subject but I feel this picture sums up what I am asking about:
[image]

Is this method different for white bread? If yes, I will appreciate advice regarding keeping white bread lasting longer as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I considered closing it as a duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-storing-bread-in-various-locations, but I think we can leave it open in case somebody has specific advice about storage of bread which is small and sweet. But to my best knowledge, there is no such advice: you have to eat them quickly, period.

Comment: That's the problem @rumtscho

People mostly look for deals and when buy many of those small and sweet breads, they know they get stale soon so they try to consume them while they are still fresh which leads to weight gain as I am aware of.

You said there's no such advice, however if I put regular bread to freezer for long storage. I can defrost it anytime if I need it. Regarding small sweet bread, rolls and all such baked dough, I wonder if storing them in refridgerator will work too.

Comment: The best way to find out if freezing works is to try it yourself and let us know your results.  If it does, then this is probably a duplicate per @rumtscho.

Comment: @logophobe freezing will work with the rolls, I am sure of that. I was more hoping that there can be answers which work for rolls and sweet stuff but not for large loaves of lean yeast or sourdough bread. I don't know anything of such methods, but this doesn't mean they don't exist :) As for the fridge, it won't work for rolls for the same reason it doesn't work for bread loaves: starches crystalize fastest at fridge temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

I am living in a new location and must buy onion rolls from the local supermarket.  No matter how fresh the date stamp, the rolls are dry and to my taste, taste stale.

I discovered that if I pop them in the microwave for 5 - 10 seconds the moisture is somehow redistributed and they soft, and moist, and almost taste like bakery rolls (ahem).

If they are too hot to handle you have microwaved them too long. If they are soggy, you have microwaved them too long.

With the sugar topping, I don't know if it would work without also melting the sugar. Give it a shot for 2 or 3 seconds.

Good luck.

Comment: I have recently popped dark bread from kitchen that got stale after 3 days into microwave. 10 seconds heating was not enough and it usually works for white bread. After taking it out and letting it sit for 1 minute, it got not just stale again but started chipping.