# Bread is too moist in a humid climate

Tags: bread, storage-method

I live in Florida, it's extremely humid here. Store bought bread and home made (bread machine) bread is always too moist for our liking.

I've read on the internet to never keep bread in the refrigerator because it will make it get stale more quickly.

I'm wondering if this might actually help our situation. What do you think, will it dry out the bread somewhat?

Do you have any suggestions? I bought a linen bread bag, which was a mistake, as the bread got stale within one day (because it was sliced I guess).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No solution, but bread going stale is at least in part due to the starch recrystallising. And 4°C (fridge) happens to be close to optimal for that.

Comment: Suggestion: can you explain what's special about diabetic bread?  Because I have solutions for normal bread, but I think that at least part of your problem is related to the alternate bread ingredients.

Comment: The diabetic bread doesn't use any flour. I use milled flax seed, vital wheat gluten and oat fiber. Here is my full list of ingredients. https://www.myfitnesspal.com/recipe/view/54457910808429 this is made in my bread machine.

Comment: @Maddy, this might help: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/effects-of-elevated-storage-temperature-on-bread-quality

Comment: I've edited your question to include that the bread is flour-free, which affects the answers you get.

Comment: I edited my question as well because it was heading in the wrong direction. It is all bread that is too moist for our liking. Not only the low carb bread.

Answer (score 2):

Flour-free breads are, in my experience, very hydroscopic: they absorb water from the air even faster than regular bread.  However, since the bread you're using is presliced, there's a simple solution: store the bread in the freezer.  Just separate the slices (so that you can pull them apart after it's frozen), and put it in a ziplock freezer bag.

This does mean that you'll need to toast, or at least thaw, the bread before using it. However, I've found that freezing bread results in less of a "stale" flavor than refrigerating it.

Comment: We do exactly this. Thawing suffices, takes minutes. If you want the bread to even less moist, pop in the microwave, each side 10 seconds, and finally another 10 seconds if it's not good enough.