# Which bread keeps the longest?

Tags: bread, food-preservation, breakfast, toasting

I want to buy the type of bread which last longest. It should be toastable, so no zwieback and other dry types. Which is the best bread for this purpose? Is the standard toast slices or loaf of bread better?

Comment: Hello Jim, you had posted two questions in one. The first (how to store bread) was a duplicate, so I removed it - see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61. I reworded the second one (which bread keeps longest) to avoid the question of "best", as that would have been misinterpreted as "tastiest", "the one the author finds best suited for making toast", etc.

Comment: Should we assume that you want to leave your bread out on the counter? If I'm not eating bread quickly, I just toss it in the freezer and it lasts practically forever and still toasts well... then it doesn't matter what kind I get, I just buy the bread I like.

Comment: @Catija:No I don't want to leave it out on the counter. I want the type that is most suited.

Comment: Most suited to what?

Comment: @Catija:For toasted bread for breakfast

Comment: Which bread you want to eat for breakfast is utterly opinion-based. Everyone has a favorite type of bread to toast and eat for breakfast.

Comment: @Catija:But I assume some breads are better preserved than others right?

Answer (score 1):

Much of it has to do with how you store it, and what the issues are in your area with that storage method in the given season (is it going to go stale before it goes moldy?)

I find that the bread that's least likely to go off before I get to the end of the loaf is sourdough ... but I get my sourdough from a place that uses a real starter, and isn't just mass produced with a sour flavor added.

... but there are also breads with additives & preservatives in them that they'll easily resist molding for more than a week ... but it doesn't make particularly good toast in my opinion.